# how to install Ansible client in yocto image

Tags: ansible, embedded-linux, yocto, yocto-recipe

I want to use Ansible to manage my embedded linux clients
so I must install python and ansible requirements(python packages).
I install python3 in my image but for running Ansible it gives error for missing some python packages recursively.

is there any recipe to  install All needed python packages for Ansible in yocto image?

Comment: I think the target system only needs to have the python interpreter and SSH access, and the ansible initiator connects via ssh and copy its modules to the target system and executes them using the python interpreter. So for Yocto, just make sure that python is in the rootfs, and make sure you ansible playbooks are valid

Comment: rootfs has python and ssh, when I run a simple command like ping from control node, it gives me an error : no module named pybase64! I install pybase and build rootfs again, it said no module named builins! and I cant add builtins package to image! i couldnt find it

Comment: Can you share the errors messages you got when trying to install ansible? Ansible can be installed using pip in a virtual env if required.

Comment: I install python in my image and when I run a command (for example: ping) on my client node(embedded linux) from ubuntu by Ansible, it gives me error that no module named base64! when I want to build base64 by yocto it gives an error: no module named builtins . and I want a list of packages needded by Ansible to install it on my image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I find a tools called pipoe.
I install pipoe on my host and create a recipe for installing python packages on my yocto image.

```
pipoe ansible
```

creates a recipe for installing all of packages that needed by ansible.